# Why do I get a Runtime exception when I try to find values I just put in the hashmap?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

Can someone please explain to me why the following snippet throws the runtime exception?

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < TOTAL; i++ ) {
    String value = "" + i;
    int key = numbers[i];                
    map.put(key, value);
}

i = 0;
for ( ; i < TOTAL; i++ ) {
    String value = "" + i;
    int key = numbers[i];
    String valueInMap = map.get(key);
    if(valueInMap == null || !valueInMap.equals(value)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Impossible!");
    }
}
```

This is the whole program except the part that I fill `numbers[]` with random numbers.

I am referring to the `throw new RuntimeException("Impossible!");` I get this exception

Comment: @Pshemo:The one in my conditional check with the text `Impossible`

Comment: Have you made any attempt at debugging? Such as printing `valueInMap` after you retrieve it?

Comment: @kdgregory:Yes it prints 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I fill `numbers[]` with random numbers.

You get an exception because not all values among `TOTAL` items in `numbers[]` are unique. When this happens, a new value overrides an old one, so in the second loop you get a wrong result.

To make sure that this never happens, put `TOTAL` random values into a `HashSet<Integer>` before copying them into the `numbers[]` array.